# What is the suitable data structure or an algorithm to find and remove items from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array like this:

```
const numbers = [{p: 1}, {p: 2}, {p: 3}, {p: 2}];
```

Now I need to write a function that takes the number, finds the items by that number, returns them and removes them from the array `number`. I have a very basic implementation of it:

```
function f(n) {
    const filtered = numbers.filter((v) => {
        return v.p === n;
    });

    filtered.forEach((v) => {
        const index = numbers.indexOf(v);
        numbers.splice(index, 1);
    });

    return filtered;
}

console.log(f(1));    // [{p: 1}]
console.log(f(2));    // [{p: 2}, {p: 2}]
console.log(numbers); // [{p: 3}]
```

But I'm wondering if it can be improved with `reduce` or something else or possibly if there's a data structure instead of an array that supports such logic?

Thanks

Comment: Why not have two functions which do one thing? Instead of a franken-function which does two? This could simplify your logic.

Comment: what makes you think it's a `franken-function`?

Comment: Hehe - Sorry, bad terminology... I meant a function with side-effects. You could have one function which filters, and one which takes those filter and strips them from `numbers`, then chain them together.

Comment: yeah, thanks, but that would be the same as I have with two pure functions

Comment: do you need to alter the source array? or do you need two new arrays?

Comment: I need to remove items from the source array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with reduceRight starting from the last value in the array, then the splice would be safe:

```js
const numbers = [{p: 1}, {p: 2}, {p: 3}, {p: 2}];

const f = val => numbers.reduceRight((arr, n, i) => {
  if (n.p === val) {
    numbers.splice(i, 1);
    arr.push(n);
  }
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(f(1)); // [{p: 1}]
console.log(f(2)); // [{p: 2}, {p: 2}]
console.log('num', numbers); // [{p: 3}]
```

Comment: same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655259/what-is-the-suitable-data-structure-or-an-algorithm-to-find-and-remove-items-fro#comment76298930_44655428)

Comment: well then just do
const f = nArr => val => nArr.reduce(... and use f(numbers)(1) or init f with 
const g = f(numbers). Then use g(1), g(2)

Comment: there you go =)

Comment: well, you're iterating the same array `console.log(nArr === numbers); // true`

Comment: my bad, you need to clone the values ofcourse but then you need to make sure you are removing correct index, see my edited answer

Comment: I think the question is more difficult than you think :). You constantly run reduce against the copy of the original array, but the elements remain the same. Besides performance hit it leads to an error in execution - add two consequent calls to `g(1)` and watch the output

Comment: true, but if you do it with reduceRight you should be safe doing splice on the array i guess

Comment: well, I'm not sure what you mean by 'why?' but the main issue was that we needed to alter the source array, and since reduceRight starts from the last index in the array and iterates toward the first index, it is safe to do the splice operation. @Maximus

Comment: [I'm not sure about that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44682323/2545680)

Comment: hrm, it is hard to get an upvote from you I guess, even if one really try to help out. Easier to just ask questions like why?, and are you sure?, isn't it. Sorry for the inconvenience @Maximus

Comment: I have no problem upvoting, but all previous implementations were buggy, that's why I didn't upvote. This one with reduceRight seems to work, but I didn't have time to verify all edge cases and you didn't explain why it works compared to using `reduce`. I will take a close look tomorrow. Definitely thanks for your efforts, that alone is probably worth an upvote, you've got it

Comment: I've got an answer here why reduceRight is working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44682425/2545680) so it seems  that your last implementation should be working fine. Accepted it, thanks :). But I'll still check tomorrow for some edge cases