# What are the consequences of mutating the array while applying Array.reduce to it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Suppose I have an array:

```
const ar = [1,2,3,4];
```

And I apply reduce function to it and inside that function I remove elements like this:

```
ar.reduce((result, element, index, original)=>{
    original.pop();
}, []);
```

The function will be executed only two times for the first two elements. That's understandable since I've removed 3rd and 4th elements during previous calls.

But what is interesting is that if I execute the function and remove the current element:

```
ar.reduce((result, element, index, original)=>{
    original.splice(index, 1);
}, []);
```

the function is still executed two times for the first two elements. Why is it not executed for the `3rd` and `4th` elements since they remain in the array?

Is this behavior documented anywhere? In a spec maybe?

Comment: Yes: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array.prototype.reduce. Because `arr[2]` and `arr[3]` don't exist anymore they are skipped (step 8.c).

Comment: When you splice an element out of the array, all the following elements move down and their indexes change. So when `.reduce()` goes to the next index, it skips over the one that moved into the current index.

Comment: As you `.splice()` the array, the remaining elements move `-1` position. And, `.reduce()` still increments its own counter `+1`. Together, they create an effective distance of `+2` for each iteration.

Comment: btw, you are not iterating the first two elements, but elment at index zero and element at index 2.

Comment: It's the same problem you run into if you write a `for()` loop that iterates over the index, and call `.splice()` in the body.

Comment: @FelixKling, thanks for the link! Just a quick follow up question - is there anything different about `reduceRight`?

Comment: @Barmar, thanks, I'll try to check it with `for` loop as you suggested. Just a quick follow up question - is there anything different about `reduceRight`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example, it is in fact executed for the *1st* and *3rd* elements, not for the first two:

```js
const ar = [1, 2, 3, 4];

ar.reduce((result, element, index, original)=>{
    console.log(element, index);
    original.splice(index, 1);
}, []);

console.log(ar);
```

```
1 2 3 4
^
```

Here, while reduce's `element` is `1` and `index` is `0`, it calls `splice`, removing the first element, then iterates to the next index:

```
2 3 4
  ^
```

Here, reduce's `element` is `3` and `index` is `1`. After removing that, `index` will be equal to `ar.length` and it stops, leaving you with

```
2 4
```

The reason `reduceRight()` will still visit all the elements is because you iterate backwards, and the previous element positions are not affected by splicing the element at the current index:

```js
const ar = [1, 2, 3, 4];

ar.reduceRight((result, element, index, original)=>{
    console.log(element, index);
    original.splice(index, 1);
}, []);

console.log(ar);
```

And the walkthrough:

```
element = 4, index = 3

1 2 3 4
      ^

element = 3, index = 2

1 2 3
    ^

element = 2, index = 1

1 2
  ^

element = 1, index = 0

1
^
```

To answer your question, yes [ECMAScript documents this behavior for `Array#reduce()` as part of the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array.prototype.reduce):

> The range of elements processed by `reduce` is set before the first call to `callbackfn`. Elements that are appended to the array after the call to `reduce` begins will not be visited by `callbackfn`. If existing elements of the array are changed, their value as passed to `callbackfn` will be the value at the time  reduce visits them; elements that are deleted after the call to `reduce` begins and before being visited are not visited.

And the exact same paragraph as above applies to `reduceRight` as well.

Below is a polyfill for `Array#reduce()`, following the steps from the specification:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'reduce', {
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  value: Array.prototype.reduce || function reduce(callbackfn) {
    "use strict";
    // 1.
    if (this === undefined || this === null) {
      throw new TypeError("Array.prototype.reduce called on null or undefined");
    }
    let O = Object(this);
    // 2.
    let len = ToLength(O.length);
    // 3.
    if (typeof callbackfn != 'function') {
      throw new TypeError(`${String(callbackfn)} is not a function`);
    }
    // 4.
    if (len == 0 && arguments.length < 2) {
      throw new TypeError("Reduce of empty array with no initial value");
    }
    // 5.
    let k = 0;

    let accumulator;
    // 6.
    if (arguments.length >= 2) {
      // a.
      accumulator = arguments[1];
    // 7.
    } else {
      // a.
      let kPresent = false;
      // b.
      while (!kPresent && k < len) {
        // i.
        let Pk = String(k);
        // ii.
        kPresent = Pk in O;
        // iii.
        if (kPresent) accumulator = O[Pk]; // 1.
        // iv.
        k++;
      }
      // c.
      if (!kPresent) throw new TypeError("Reduce of empty array with no initial value");
    }
    // 8.
    while (k < len) {
      // a.
      let Pk = String(k);
      // b.
      let kPresent = Pk in O;
      // c.
      if (kPresent) {
        // i.
        let kValue = O[Pk];
        // ii.
        accumulator = callbackfn(accumulator, kValue, k, O);
      }
      // d.
      k++;
    }
    // 9.
    return accumulator;
  }
});

function ToInteger(argument) {
  let number = Number(argument);

  if (isNaN(number)) return 0;

  switch (number) {
  case 0:
  case Infinity:
  case -Infinity:
    return number;
  }

  return parseInt(number);
}

function ToLength(argument) {
  let len = ToInteger(argument);

  if (len <= 0) return 0;
  if (len == Infinity) return Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER || Math.pow(2, 53) - 1;

  return len;
}
```

Comment: thanks, can you make a summary of all comments so this answer is full and I'll accept it?

Comment: and one clarifying question - is there anything different about `reduceRight`?

Comment: yeah, I meant in terms of skipping indexes?

Comment: @Maximus I'm pretty much finished updating now, unless someone finds a bug or a compliant simplication in my polyfill. Is there anything else you want me to clarify?

Comment: thanks a lot, it's interesting that splice with reduce right doesn't skip the elements

Comment: @Maximus not really. Just think about the the index iteration and what element is getting removed. I can update the answer with a walk-through example, but I feel like putting a polyfill for `reduceRight` would be over-kill

Comment: yeah, thanks, no polyfill is required, a walk-through for reduce right would be a great addition though :) it's late here, I'll take a fresh look tomorrow